# Refactor a code of selection a validator

Tags: c#, validation, if-statement, strategy-pattern

I have a datatable and have to validate every field in it. I have refactor this code to this below, but a complexity is 15(!!)  Should I make something like dictionary with type as Key and Func as Value? I'd be very grateful for some ideas

```
private bool CheckField(DataRow dataRow, ValidationField validationField)
        {
            bool result = false;
            if (validationField.Requiered)
            {
                if (validationField.Type == typeof (int))
                {
                    result = this.CheckIntegerAndNotNull(dataRow[validationField.Name].ToString());
                }
                else if (validationField.Type == typeof (DateTime))
                {
                    result = this.CheckDateTimeAndNotNull(dataRow[validationField.Name].ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (validationField.Type == typeof (int))
                {
                    result = this.CheckIntegerOrNull(dataRow[validationField.Name].ToString());
                }
                else if (validationField.Type == typeof(DateTime))
                {
                    result = this.CheckDateTimeOrNull(dataRow[validationField.Name].ToString());
                }
                else if (validationField.Type == typeof(string))
                {
                    result = this.CheckStringOrNull(dataRow[validationField.Name].ToString(),
                        validationField.MaxLength.Value);
                }
                else if (validationField.Type == typeof(decimal))
                {
                    result = this.CheckDecimalOrNull(dataRow[validationField.Name].ToString());
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

 public class ValidationField
    {
        public Type Type { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Requiered  { get; set; }
        public int? MaxLength { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing working code. Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: _"Should I make something like dictionary with type as Key and Func as Value?"_ - yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Bring this out of if statement

   if (validationField.Type == typeof (int))
   {
       result = this.CheckIntegerAndNotNull(dataRow[validationField.Name].ToString());
   }
   else if (validationField.Type == typeof (DateTime))
   {
       result = this.CheckDateTimeAndNotNull(dataRow[validationField.Name].ToString());
   }
2. Save value of dataRow[validationField.Name] to local variable (maybe also dataRow[validationField.Name].ToString())
3. Use switch for ValidationField.Type (you may need to create Enum)